# Change input language doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to change the keyboard input language and set it to English from C# (I need an .exe for do it), the problem is that the program works in Visual Studio, but when I launch the .exe it doesn't change the keyboard.

I have this in the main method on a winforms app

```
static void Main(){
    InputLanguage englishLayout = GetInputLanguageByName("english");
    if (englishLayout!=null) {
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = englishLayout;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("nulo.");
    }
```

This method searches the installed languages

```
public static InputLanguage GetInputLanguageByName(string inputName){
    foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages){
        Console.WriteLine(lang.LayoutName);
        if (lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToLower().StartsWith(inputName))
            return lang;
         }
    return null;
}
```

Just need that from the application (do not need forms, just change the keyboard language), but when I launch the .exe outside Visual Studio it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you verify whether this works or not?

Comment: Have you tried running it whilst under administrator mode? I have a feeling that might be causing it

Comment: yes, I already have executed it like admin but doesn't work. From visual Studio works perfectly, and if I put the code like a function called from an form textbox click event, it works. But not in the main from the exe . The way i see it works is because the language in the toolbar changes.

Comment: is it because you did not focus on the textbox before changing the input language?